# Writing a Value to the Stack in the own process

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have no luck this time, I had a wonderful script to write STACK Values to an address of my own process, but I kinda lost the script and I had to recode it. Somehow it doesn't really work :\

Here is my Script:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>

NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory()
{
    //path to the documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}

bool writeStack(vm_address_t offset,  long data) {

//declaring global variables

    kern_return_t err;
    mach_port_t port = mach_task_self();

//set memory protections to allow us writing code there

    err = vm_protect(port, (vm_address_t) offset, sizeof(data), NO,VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE | VM_PROT_COPY);

//check if it fails

    if (err != KERN_SUCCESS || !MACH_PORT_VALID(port))
        {
            //information to write if it fails
            NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Info\n\nPort:%d\nAddress: %p\nMach Task Self:%d\nData: %ld",port,offset,mach_task_self(),data];
            [info writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/fail.txt",applicationDocumentsDirectory()] atomically:YES];
                return FALSE;
        }

//write code to memory

    if (vm_write(port, (vm_address_t) offset, (vm_address_t)&data, sizeof(data))) {

        NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Info\n\nPort:%d\nAddress: %p\nMach Task Self:%d\nData: %ld",port,offset,mach_task_self(),data];
        [info writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/writeprob.txt",applicationDocumentsDirectory()] atomically:YES];
    }

//set the protections back to normal so the game runs without problems

err = vm_protect(port, (vm_address_t)offset, sizeof(data), NO,VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_EXECUTE);

 NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Info\n\nPort:%d\nAddress: %p\nMach Task Self:%d\nData: %ld",port,offset,mach_task_self(),data];
    [info writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/success.txt",applicationDocumentsDirectory()] atomically:YES];

        return TRUE;

}
```

When I look at my documents directory, it said "success.txt" and I dont see any part of the code that could cause problems. It works all out, besides the VALUE is not written :\
I checked several things, my app doesnt have ASLR, I have enough permissions since its my own process...

Any ideas what might fail? thanks much

Comment: how much data are you trying to write? From how this looks you're writing 4 bytes

Comment: Well, the size is sizeof(data) which can be 1, 2 or 4 byte.. I am tried to write value 99 and 8722 (randomly chosen) to stack

Comment: ok, based on your code it's only going to be 4 bytes, not 1 or 2 (just an fyi). Was just making sure you had that correct

Comment: Okay, if you are sure, I tested writing 4 byte 87 22 33 44 (87223344) but it still doesnt work :\ Any other idea?

Comment: negative D: I'll keep thinking though - what version of iOS is this?

Comment: its version 6.1.. well honestly its jailbroken and I am writing a dylib to "hijack" a process.. and so my dylib is running as a subprocess therefore I can write to stack of the process. Its all legal btw :)

Comment: are you on IRC? I could help you right now

Comment: what server and what channel? I'll join it :)

Comment: irc.saurik.com #iphone

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself guys!

The problem was: When I wrote a value to the heap, it worked, but the Application overwrote that value at the beginning right after I wrote it. Therefore I added something to kinda 'freeze' the value. Not actually freezing, but keep writing to the address (in an infinite loop)

The code I used:

```
    CFRunLoopTimerContext theContext = {0, nil, NULL, NULL, NULL};
CFRunLoopTimerRef theTimer = CFRunLoopTimerCreate(
    NULL, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), 0.01, 0, 0,
    (CFRunLoopTimerCallBack)writeStack, &theContext);
CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), theTimer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

This makes an infinite loop which runs every 0.01 second. And in the void writeStack() {} function I simply do:

1 Byte:

```
*((uin8_t*)(0xADDRESS)) = 0xDATA;
```

2 Byte:

```
*((uin16_t*)(0xADDRESS)) = CFSwapInt16(0xDATA);
```

and 4 Byte:

```
*((uin32_t*)(0xADDRESS)) = CFSwapInt32(0xDATA);
```

Thanks for the help guys ;)